# Laravel - Master password / Log into other accounts?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

I have developed a nutrition platform that I'm using with my clients. It's somewhat similar to MyFitnessPal.

Some of my clients need help refining their diets so I need to log into their account to make changes to their plan.

What's the best option to achieve this? I thought of maybe having a master password that lets me log into any clients account but I don't know how to implement this.

My postLogin() method in the LoginController doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: you can have this in your main login function. Have maybe an OR condition to compare passwords or something. This would go alot faster if you post some code

Comment: I'm using the pre-existing Laravel login & register methods.

Comment: Why is this needed as a login? Shouldn't your administration panel handle modifying things such as that? Master password is a very bad idea, should anyone get hold of it, suddenly they have access to everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our applications we have a route/controller method in the admin backend that does something like `auth()->login($user);` then redirects you to the route the usual user would go to when they first login.

Docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Comment: Cheers mate. I didn't think of doing that but just coded it up now and it works perfectly :-)